# Uploading large Files 2gb + ColdFusion, Apache

Tags: apache, file-upload, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

We have upgraded to ColdFusion 10 and I am testing large upload capability.

Using both a HTML form and the flash multi-file upload CFFILEUPLOAD I can upload files of up to 2GB.

With files over 2gb the upload does not even start. 0% both with the flash upload and what chrome browser reports with HTML form.

Technical services suggest it does not even get as far as Apache, that is not restricting the upload. ColdFusion is also setup to allow 4000MB post data even with throttle.

The upload is occurring across the network, so even with test a 1.7gb file it doesn't take long - but 2.5gb does not even begin.

Any suggestions to help diagnose the cause?

Thanks

Comment: If it doesn't even start, it's probably a browser issue, especially since you say it "does not even get as far as Apache". Why are you trying to upload multi-GB files through a web browser? Have you considered FTP/rsync/etc?

Comment: The files need to be linked to database records and stored on a server without ftp access. Previously I did this by having them upload to another FTP server - then use ajax/cfftp to browse the file and copy it to the production server. However this is not ideal and the ajax is flakey. I need a solution for website editors to upload several gb videos to the website.

Comment: Hmm, well maybe look into whatever Youtube/Vimeo/etc do, assuming they allow files that big. Also probably relevant stuff here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=upload+large+videos - some of those suggest a client plugin that breaks it into small chunks and uploads individually.

Comment: Thanks I will look into these things.

Comment: Using FF with the Cffileupload, it gets to 98/99% and now I see an error on the server "Invalid Content-Length"